# laravel eger loading not working properly when i use limit or take in whereIn

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$all_5_post = wp_terms::with(['wp_posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5);
        }])->whereIn('id',[3,4,6,9])->get();
```

getting relationship data in 3 id but 4,6,9 relationship data getting empty but when i only use WHERE eloquent  and doing multiple query for same 3,4,6,9 id it showing 5 relationship table data in each
what i have to do now i need a solution.

Comment: take 5 isn't take 5 per relationship, it is take 5 total ... it isn't a single query per relationship, it is one single query that gets all the related records for all the wp_terms you are returning ... which means after it gets 5 it doesn't take any more, which means 1 single `wp_terms` could return 5 `wp_posts` and the next `wp_terms` would have none, because only 5 were taken total

Answer (score 0):

like  lagbox said in his comment, the 'take' statement will take five for all of query results not five for every result ....

to solve this, you can use [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

first: install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

second:  use it in your models like:

1-in main class model:

```
class wp_terms extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

  .....
}
```

2- in sub class model:

```
class wp_posts extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

now you could write:

```
$all_5_post = wp_terms::with(['wp_posts' => function ($query) {
                                      $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(5);
                                }])->whereIn('id',[3,4,6,9])->get();
```

and you should get the result you expected ...

remember: use 'limit' not 'take'

Comment: getting Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns error